# UISearchBar stays on NavigationController after pressing the back button

Tags: ios, swift3, uisearchbar

I have a `UISearchBar` attached to the `UINavigationController` and when I tap the back button of the presented `UIViewController` which contains the `UISearchBar` it doesn't disappear as I expected, it stays still attached to the nav bar and appears on the parent view controller.

Here's my `UISearchBar` declaration:

```
lazy var searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar()
    sb.placeholder = "Search"

    UITextField.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(red: 230, green: 230, blue: 230) // cor de fundo da search bar
    sb.delegate = self
    return sb
}()
```

Here's how I attach the `UISearchBar` to the `UINavigationController`

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)
```

I tried ti call `searchBar.removeFromSuperview()` on the `viewWillDisappear` but it didn't worked.

Any hint?

Thank you

Comment: try with `self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar` for adding and for remove `self.navigationItem.titleView = nil`

Comment: it did work, but somehow when I push the nav-c again my searchBar background color disappeared, but that's a different issue I think. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar` for adding the search bar instead of `navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)` and when you need to remove it then replace the titleView by another `UIView` or make it = nil

**to Add**

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = searchBar
```

**to Remove**

```
self.navigationItem.titleView = UIView()
```